# how to do a binary search without using an array in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a binary search that doesn't use an array. It also needs to count how many searches it does until it finds the number. I also have to use a randomaccessfile.

```
RandomAccessFile raf=new RandomAccessFile(new File("Project 10"),"rw");

//writing in random numbers. Different numbers will be used when it is being tested

raf.writeInt(-5);
raf.writeInt(-1);
raf.writeInt(122);
raf.writeInt(124);
raf.writeInt(125);
raf.writeInt(256);
```

user input what number do you want to search for. I need to do this without using the scanner class. the method to do this will be very helpful

I know this is how you do a binary search with an array. I need help figuring out how to do it without an array

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] list, int key) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = list.length - 1;

    while (high >= low) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (key < list[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else if (key == list[mid])
            return mid;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
    }
    return -low - 1; // Now high<low, key not found
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use an array? And Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: You don't need an *array* necessarily, but a requirement for performing binary search within an O(log(n)) bound is that you have random access to the elements. If you don't (say, with a linked list,) then you can still do the search, but you'll spend a lot of time scanning through the elements just to find the nth element, rather than finding the target element. I note that you do currently have a random access file; that would seem to fit the bill, no?

Comment: can you use a List?  ps. dont forget to sort your collection before ding your search!

Comment: Why? What is your motiviation? Do you want to search in huge sorted files?

Comment: @AlexWien This is very likely a homework problem of some sort; note the comment that "Different numbers will be used when it is being tested", or the name of the file, "Project 10".

Comment: It's obvious this is a homework assignment.  You can basically assume that any question that mentions a _Scanner_ is homework.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a java specific question as much as it is an algorithms questions.
Though not stated, your binarySearch is obviously predicated on the file somehow magically getting sorted.

That said, you know that the raf.writeInt(xxx) is going to write a normalized byte-length value to the file. Treat the file itself as an array where each index position is 
a[i * 4] == so, create little functions that compute 'mid' 'low' and 'high' as multiples of the desired index.

Google for "external sorting"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an array or a List if you treat your file as the array.  Assuming the file is sorted, the pseudo code would go something like

1. Get the number of lines in the file (may need to guess...not sure how you could count new lines)
2. Read the value at 1/2 the total number of lines
3. If the value is same, done.  If smaller, repeat using the first half of the file.  If larger, repeat with the second half of the file.

Comment: would something like this work? I'm still using pseudo code because im still trying to figure out how to get user input without using the scanner class. Would bufferedreader be a good option?

Comment: I think you will need to use something like java.io.RandomAccessFile.  You need to be able to seek within the file, since you are not reading it linearly.  You will need to jump to a spot in the file, start reading until you see the new line, then read an int (there is a method on RandomAccessFile for that).

Answer (score 0):

```
Would something like this work?

public static int binarySearch(int raf//for the file?, int key//for input?){
int low=0;
int high=raf.length()-1
while (high>=low){
int mid=(low+high)/2;
if (key<raf.[mid])// Does the [] automatically make it an array
high=mid-1;
else if (key==raf.[mid])
return mid;
else
low=mid+1;
}
return-low-1//now high < low, key not found
}
}
```